# How do I create an array of objects with a nested array based on a similar key?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array that looks something like this

```
const example = [
  { id: '1', name: 'Person 1', organization: { id: '11', name: 'Organization A' } },
  { id: '2', name: 'Person 2', organization: { id: '12', name: 'Organization A' } },
  { id: '3', name: 'Person 3', organization: { id: '13', name: 'Organization B' } },
];
```

As you can see, the `organization` name is something I want to key off of and create a data structure like this:

```
const output = [
  // data.value will be their ID
  { 
    organizationName: 'Organization A', 
    data: [
      { label: 'Person 1', value: '1' },
      { label: 'Person 2', value: '2' },
    ],
  },
  { 
    organizationName: 'Organization B', 
    data: [
      { label: 'Person 3', value: '3' },
    ],
  },
]
```

#### What I've tried

I know I want to use `reduce` for something like this, but I feel like I'm off:

```
const providerOptions = externalPeople.data.reduce((acc, currentValue) => {
  const {
    organization: { name: organizationName },
  } = currentValue;
  if (organizationName) {
    acc.push({ organization: organizationName, data: [] });
  } else {
    const { name: externalPersonName, id } = currentValue;
    acc[acc.length - 1].data.push({ name: externalPersonName, value: id });
  }
  return acc;
}, [] as any);
```

However the output comes out to something like this:

```
[
  {organizationName: 'Organization A', data: []},
  {organizationName: 'Organization A', data: []},
  {organizationName: 'Organization B', data: []},
];
```

`data` doesn't seem to get anything pushed inside the array in this reduce function, and the organization name get duplicated... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't seem to check if `organizationName` already exists in `acc`

Comment: You also ignore the data for the first time you see the org.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way is to use an Map/Set/or object to keep track of orgs you create. This way you are not searching in the array to see if the organization was found already. After you are done, you can create the array you want from the object.

```js
const externalPeople = { 
  data : [
    { id: '1', name: 'Person 1', organization: { id: '11', name: 'Organization A' } },
    { id: '2', name: 'Person 2', organization: { id: '12', name: 'Organization A' } },
    { id: '3', name: 'Person 3', organization: { id: '13', name: 'Organization B' } },
  ],
};

const providerOptions = Object.values(externalPeople.data.reduce((acc, currentValue) => {
  const {
    organization: { name: organizationName },
    name: externalPersonName,
    id
  } = currentValue;

  // Is the org new? Yes, create an entry for it
  if (!acc[organizationName]) {
    acc[organizationName] = { organization: organizationName, data: [] };
  }

  // push the person to the organization
  acc[organizationName].data.push({ name: externalPersonName, value: id });

  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(providerOptions)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution

```js
const example = [
  { id: '1', name: 'Person 1', organization: { id: '11', name: 'Organization A' } },
  { id: '2', name: 'Person 2', organization: { id: '12', name: 'Organization A' } },
  { id: '3', name: 'Person 3', organization: { id: '13', name: 'Organization B' } },
];

const result = example.reduce((res, entry) => {
 const recordIndex = res.findIndex(rec => rec.organizationName === entry.organization.name);
 if(recordIndex >= 0) {
   res[recordIndex].data.push({ label: entry.name, value: entry.id});
 } else {
   const record = {
     organizationName: entry.organization.name,
     data: [{ label: entry.name, value: entry.id }]
   };
   res.push(record);
 }
  return res;
}, []);
  console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking if the value is already present in your accumulation *acc*

You can check it with a simple *find* in the if statement since it's an array

```
const providerOptions = externalPeople.data.reduce((acc, currentValue) => {
    const {
        organization: { name: organizationName },
    } = currentValue;

    //Check if organization is not present already
    if (!acc.find(a => a.organization === organizationName)) {
        //Add also the data of the element your are processing
        acc.push({ organization: organizationName, data: [{label: currentValue.name, value: currentValue.id}] });
    } else {
        const { name: externalPersonName, id } = currentValue;
        acc[acc.length - 1].data.push({ label: externalPersonName, value: id });
    }
    return acc;
}, [] as any);
```

I also added the data of the first element of the group you create when adding the organization.

The result should be as your expected output:

```
[
  {
    organization: 'Organization A',
    data: [
      { label: 'Person 1', value: '1' },
      { label: 'Person 2', value: '2' }
    ]
  },
  {
    organization: 'Organization B',
    data: [
      { label: 'Person 3', value: '3' }
    ]
  }
]
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Compare this solution (using Lodash) with other solutions. Which one emphasises your intentions at most? This is why we use Lodash in our company - to maintain code as declarative as we can, because code readability, with minimum cognitive overload, is most important goal during coding.

```
const persons = [
  { id: '1', name: 'Person 1', organization: { id: '11', name: 'Organization A' } },
  { id: '2', name: 'Person 2', organization: { id: '12', name: 'Organization A' } },
  { id: '3', name: 'Person 3', organization: { id: '13', name: 'Organization B' } },
];

const personsByOrganizations = _.groupBy(persons, 'organization.name')

const output = _.map(personsByOrganizations, (persons, organizationName) => ({
  organizationName,
  data: _.map(persons, ({ name, id }) => ({
    label: name,
    value: id
  }))
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that with using a `Set`?

```js
result = [...new Set(example.map(d => d.organization.name))].map(label => {
  return {
    organizationName: label,
    data: example.filter(d => d.organization.name === label).map(d => {
      return {label: d.name, value: d.id}
    })
  }
})
```

`